# YTD Measure not working in DAX when the date slicer is set to previous year

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, measure, calculated-field

Here is the test data:

[image]

Here is the date Data:

```
Dates = CALENDAR(date(2022,1,1),TODAY())
```

Relationship between the tables:
[image]

**Question: Create a Measure that shows the YTD Total amount for the current year, even if the date slicer starts from the previous year:**

**Here is my code:**

```
YTD = 
VAR minim = CALCULATE( MIN( Dates[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date]))
var startyear = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)
return if( minim >= startyear , 
calculate(sum(test[Totals] ), FILTER(Dates, Dates[Date] >= startyear))  ,  
 calculate(sum(test[Totals] ), FILTER(Dates, Dates[Date] >= startyear)) )
```

**Test Scenario 1 Works fine:  Shows correct info,** the date slicer starts at 2022, and the measure shows the YTD result of the current year

[image]

**Test Scenario 2: Does Not Work,** Shows 40 instead of 130
[image]

**Test Scenario 3: Does not work,** Even when the year is the current year
[image]

Comment: In your measure in IF condition both True and False are same expression. One needs to be changed

Comment: Hi Ashok, Yes, I want to show the YTD amount for the current year, for both scenarios and dates before 1/1/2023 or after 1/1/2023

Comment: @StackOne The YTD measure shouldn't be filtered by the dates slicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YTD formula will help you get the correct output/result.

```
YTD = 
    VAR minim = CALCULATE( MIN( Dates[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date]))
    VAR startyear = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1)
    return if( minim >= startyear , 
            CALCULATE(SUM(test[Totals]), test[Date] >= startyear, REMOVEFILTERS(Dates[Date])),  
            CALCULATE(SUM(test[Totals]), test[Date] >= startyear, REMOVEFILTERS(Dates[Date])) )
```

[image]

Simply you can use the following formula for the YTD.

```
YTD = CALCULATE(SUM(test[Totals]), YEAR(test[Date]) = YEAR(TODAY()), REMOVEFILTERS(Dates[Date]))
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I also found that we can use the following code. 

```
YTD2 = 
VAR minim = CALCULATE( MIN( Dates[Date]), ALLSELECTED(Dates[Date])) //12-10-2022
var startyear = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1) // current start year date 1-1-2023
var a= if( minim >= startyear ,
calculate(sum(test[Totals] ), FILTER(all(Dates), Dates[Date] >= startyear))  ,  
 calculate(sum(test[Totals] ), FILTER(all(Dates), Dates[Date] >= startyear))
 
  )
 return a

Comment: Yes, it works. Simply 
`YTD2 = CALCULATE(SUM(test[Totals] ), FILTER(ALL(Dates), YEAR(Dates[Date]) = YEAR(TODAY())))`

Comment: For the last year (2022), `YTD2 = CALCULATE(SUM(test[Totals] ), FILTER(ALL(Dates), YEAR(Dates[Date]) = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **AllSelected** change to **All** since all selected keeps the slicer filter

YTD = TOTALYTD(sum(test[Totals]),all(Dates[Date]))

Comment: Nope that's not right, All will consider everything from start date, that is 1/1/2022

Comment: I have provided the measure it will only take for the current year.

Comment: I tried it, it works